# Use TableStorage for BotFramework v4

Tags: node.js, database, azure, botframework, azure-table-storage

Currently I have implemented Bots using Azure Cosmos DB. I manage state data (userstate, conversationstate) with the state accessors.

A sample of how I use it:

```
// Use AutosaveStateMiddleware
adapter.use(new AutoSaveStateMiddleware(conversationState));
adapter.use(new AutoSaveStateMiddleware(userState));

// Read State from DB 
const conversationData = await this.conversationDataAccessor.get(turnContext, {});
const user = await this.userDataAccessor.get(turnContext, {});

// Manipulate state
conversationData.roundCounter = 1;
userData.name = "John Doe";

// Save to cache
await this.userDataAccessor.set(turnContext, user);
await this.conversationDataAccessor.set(turnContext, conversationData);

// Save changes to DB (persistent)
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(turnContext);
await this.userState.saveChanges(turnContext);
```

I consider switching to a table storage solution, since it is much cheaper than Cosmos DB.

Unfortunately, I only found a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state-azure-table-storage?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) for BotFramework v3.

Is there a way to use a table storage in a similar fashion? If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some additional hints for setting up the DB:

The syntax from the article didn't work for me. I used this instead:

```
const { BlobStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');

// Add Blobstorage
const memoryStorage = new BlobStorage({
   containerName: 'CONTAINERNAME',
   storageAccountOrConnectionString: 'CONNECTIONSTRING',
})
```

You can find the info under "keys" in your storage resource on Azure.